# How to align input box

Tags: html, css

I have text and input box, I want to align text and input box, but with no lucky. What is the idea to do that? What is the process/steps (or how you think of this problem) you use to solve this kind of problem?

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <div>
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name)
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name)
            </div>
            <div>
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ComputerID)
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ComputerID)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ComputerID)
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4" style="background-color:lavenderblush;">.col-sm-4</div>
        <div class="col-sm-4" style="background-color:lavender;">.col-sm-4</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[screenshot of UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MC9uW.png)

Comment: Please, post your HTML that has been *generated by razor*. You can simply do this by inspecting the container element in your browser and copying the specific html.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<form class="form-inline">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputName2">Name</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputName2" placeholder="Jane Doe">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputEmail2">Email</label>
    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail2" placeholder="jane.doe@example.com">
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Send invitation</button>
</form>
```